# Resovling dependencies while hosting on Railway

Tags: reactjs, hosting, railway

I'm trying to host a webiste on railway.app and it gives dependecy error because of react notification badge which might have been deprecated
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFcwc.png)

While im able to run this locally because i can use npm i --force but in railway no such option is provided, I tried all solutions provided by ChatGPT but none of them worked.
[i can change only the build command which makes no difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeNRp.png)